# Google Add-on gives error "URL Fetch URL Length" only when published

Tags: google-apps-script, jira-rest-api, urlfetch

I've been working on this bug for a while now, I can't seem to figure it out, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

This code is to integrate JIRA and Google Sheets, the problem is that once the number of issues I'm importing exceeds 62, it gives an error of "URL Fetch URL Length". Now the tricky part is that this only happens when the add-on is published (domain-wide, in case that matters). When the code is bound or working in **testing** mode, it works for as many keys as I want.

It currently works by splitting the request into groups of 30 and sending for them separately, which is why the number 62 seems to make no sense.

I've tried a work-around where the array of issues the code sends for is only made up of the first 62 keys that are on the sheet, but so long as there are more than 62 issues written on the sheet, it still fails.

The entire code is on GitHub at: https://github.com/ngovil/Jira_Google-Sheets_Integration.git

This is is how the array is split up:

```
     for(var divideby = 0; divideby < Math.ceil(vals.length/batchsize); divideby++){
     var data = getStories(divideby);
     if (data == "") {
         return;
     }
     var numberofrepeats = -1;
     var beginat = -1;
     if(divideby*batchsize+batchsize>=vals.length) numberofrepeats = vals.length;
     else{
        for(var i=0; i<vals2.length; i++){
          if(vals2[i][0] === vals[divideby*batchsize + batchsize][0]){
            numberofrepeats = i;
            i=vals2.length;
          }
        }
      }
```

This is how the data is sent for:

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var sheeturl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
    var allData = {issues:[]};
    var data = {startAt:0,maxResults:0,total:1};
    var startAt = 0;
    Logger.log("Making request for %s entries", C_MAX_RESULTS);
    var inter = ["search?jql="];
    if(divideby*30+30>=vals.length) var numberofrepeats = vals.length;
    else numberofrepeats = divideby*30 + 30;
    for (var i = divideby*30; i < numberofrepeats; i++) {
        if(i==numberofrepeats-1) inter.push("issue%20%3D%20", vals[i][0], "%20order%20by%20rank%20&maxResults=", C_MAX_RESULTS, "&startAt=", startAt);
        else inter.push("issue%20%3D%20", vals[i][0], "%20or%20");
    }

    var interStr = inter.join("");
    var temp = getDataForAPI(interStr);
    if(temp == "") return temp;
    data =  JSON.parse(temp);  
    allData.issues = allData.issues.concat(data.issues);
    startAt = data.startAt + data.maxResults;

    return allData;
```

Comment: Does the JIRA API specify the request has to be in the URL? Does the API really require more then 62 keys to make a request?  Can you break the request down into smaller requests and rebuild them?

Comment: Currently, I'm already breaking the request into groups of 30 and sending for them that way.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to publish this add-on from a different account and it now works perfectly. It seems like there might be a bug in how it was compiled. Thanks to anyone who spent time on this problem!